# A bound on number of elements less than $n$ of a $B_2[g]$ sequence

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $S \subset \mathbb{N}$. We say $S$ is of type $B_2(g)$ if the number of representation
of the form $n = s_1 + s_2 \ (s_1 \leq s_2)$ is bounded by $g$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Let $S(n)$ be the number of elements of $S$ not exceeding $n$.

Is it reasonable to expect
$S(n) \leq n^{1/2}$? If so, could someone please explain to me why? Thank you.

Comment: Probably not. The sequence $\{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ... \}$ is $B_2(1)$ and it is tight $S(n)=n^{1/2}$. Increasing $g$ is only going to make things worse.

Comment: Actually, $S = \{1,2,4,9,16,25,...\}$  is $B_2(2)$, so you can certainly construct examples for which $S(n) > n^{1/2}$ for all $n>1$.